Unexpected runtime benchmarks with C++20 ranges
Here 'myData' is a vector of integer. I filter only even numbers from this and transform these even numbers into string. These are stored in a vector and returned.
This function is called and we call process function on each element of returned vector.
I tried to use std::ranges to optimize away creation of this vector and instead return a view.
Original code:
auto getData() {
        std::vector<T2> v;
        for (T1 p: myData) {
            if (filter(p))
                v.push_back(transform(p));
        }
        return v;
}

Update-1: Modified to use return a lambda
Returned lambda takes a callable and calls it for each element. Effectively similar to lazy view.
This outperforms original code by 2.5X.
auto getDataCallback() {
    return [this](auto func) {
        for (T1 p: myData) {
            if (filter(p))
                func(transform(p));
        }
    };
}

Update-2: Return std::view instead of vector
auto dataView() {
        return myData | ranges::views::filter(filter) | ranges::views::transform([this](auto t) { return transform(t); });
}

I expected this perform similar to with Update-1.
But benchmarks show that its 1.7X slower Update-1
Why is std::view based approach 1.7X slower than lambda based approach ?
Here is benchmark link: https://quick-bench.com/q/3QMVqBVFU0ma7EN3q9_ADnIA_IM

I expect almost same runtime for 2nd and 3rd solution but not sure if i am doing anything wrong here.
Here is complete code:
#include <ranges>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

static inline constexpr size_t million = 1000;  //1000000;
static inline size_t sum = 0;

using T1 = int;
using T2 = std::string;
bool filter(T1 t) { return  0 == t % 2; }
void process(const T2 &p) { sum += p.size(); };
T2 transform(T1 x) { return std::to_string(x); }
static inline std::vector<T1> data;

namespace Conventional {
    class MyClass {
        std::vector<T1>& myData = data;
        T2 transform(T1 x) { return std::to_string(x); }

    public:
        auto getData() {
            std::vector<T2> v;
            for (T1 p: myData) {
                if (filter(p))
                    v.push_back(transform(p));
            }
            return v;
        }
    };

    void myFunc() {
        sum = 0;
        MyClass obj;
        auto data = obj.getData();
        std::for_each(data.begin(), data.end(), process);
    }
};

namespace LazyCpp17 {
    class MyClass {
        std::vector<T1>& myData = data;
        T2 transform(T1 x) { return std::to_string(x); }

    public:
        auto getDataCallback() {
            return [this](auto func) {
                for (T1 p: myData) {
                    if (filter(p))
                        func(transform(p));
                }
            };
        }
    };

    void myFunc() {
        sum = 0;
        MyClass obj;
        obj.getDataCallback()(process);
    }
};

namespace LazyCpp20 {
    class MyClass {
        std::vector<T1>& myData = data;
        T2 transform(T1 x) { return std::to_string(x); }

    public:
        auto dataView() {
            return myData | std::views::filter(filter) | std::views::transform([this](auto t) { return transform(t); });
        }
    };

    void myFunc() {
        sum = 0;
        MyClass obj;
        std::ranges::for_each(obj.dataView(), process);
    }
};


static void ConventionalB(benchmark::State& state) {
  data.resize(million);
  std::iota(data.begin(), data.end(), 0);
  // Code inside this loop is measured repeatedly
  for (auto _ : state) {
        Conventional::myFunc();
    // Make sure the variable is not optimized away by compiler
  }
}
// Register the function as a benchmark
BENCHMARK(ConventionalB);

static void LazyCpp17B(benchmark::State& state) {
  data.resize(million);
  std::iota(data.begin(), data.end(), 0);
  // Code before the loop is not measured
  std::string x = "hello";
  for (auto _ : state) {
        LazyCpp17::myFunc();
  }
}
BENCHMARK(LazyCpp17B);

static void LazyCpp20B(benchmark::State& state) {
  data.resize(million);
  std::iota(data.begin(), data.end(), 0);
  // Code before the loop is not measured
  std::string x = "hello";
  for (auto _ : state) {
        LazyCpp20::myFunc();
  }
}
BENCHMARK(LazyCpp20B);


First of all, you data vector is empty. You should fix it with the static inline std::vector<T1> data(million);. The results will differ then. Even after that it will contain zeros and your 'filter' function is useless. If you fix this the results will differ even more. Show the fixed code and let's continue the comparison.

Thanks, I missed that part while copy code my my IDE to benhcmarks. Updated now

Unrelated to the question, but I'd clean the code a bit. There's std::string x = "hello"; that have no reason to be; there's 3 T2 transform(T1 x) { return std::to_string(x); } members that are not really needed, as you have a global version of it; naming the predicate you pass to filter filter is just confusing; the same holds for the function you pass to transform, it should not be named transform; the [this](auto t) { return transform(t); } lambda is really redundant, and it could be be just f, where f is a bettern name than transform.

And T1 and T2 are obfuscating code. If you really wanted to be ready to swap std::string with something else in a localized way, you could still choose a better name like String, instead of T2.

One extra note, your Conventional case collects results to a vector and other options don't, so this options couldn't be compared with the other two. One thing is to process filtered items and convert it, throwing result to nowhere (which gives freedom to optimizer), another thing is to actually allocate and reallocate memory.

Also, for_each takes a projection argument. You could use that, instead of transform in the pipeline.

I still think that the benchmark you've devised is not fair. Or, at least, should be improved. First and formost, the alternatives you're comparing should have the same signature, in the sense that they should be given the same types of inputs and return the same type of output. This was not the case in the original benchmark. Secondly, the data should be randomly generated, rather than via std::iota.
(In the following I've excluded the case where you allocate a std::vector<std::string> to store intermediate results. That's worse than the approach 2, which is still <range>-less, so there's no point in taking case 1 in consideration.)
I think these two functions are those to be compared:
auto cpp17(std::vector<int> const& v) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int x : v) {
        if (pred(x)) {
            sum += strlen(x);
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

auto cpp20(std::vector<int> const& v) {
    auto w = v | std::views::filter(pred)
               | std::views::transform(strlen);
    return std::accumulate(w.begin(), w.end(), 0);
}

to which the following, using range-v3's ranges::accumulate, can be added (not sure why ranges::views::filter is not found!):
auto cpp17v3(std::vector<int> const& v) {
    return ranges::accumulate(v | std::ranges::views::filter(pred), 0, std::plus{}, strlen);
}

(In both cases, strlen is composition of std::to_string and .size.)
It seems that Clang behaves better:

However, I wouldn't take such a benchmark as a gospel.
For instance, look at these two:


The former's cpp17 and cpp20 are the same identical things as the latter's cpp17 and cpp17v3, but the benchmark gives different results, just because I've added a third participant to the race!
But I wouldn't rush to blame QuickBench either, tbh.
The benchmark should be made such that, for instance, the std::vector<int> has random ints, instead of being just an iota.

I wouldn't say that benchmark is not fair or compiler (optimizer, really) is not good good enough (which is confirmed by the original benchmark with CLang). It is all about the usage of the views/pipelines by Shakti in a way the compiler struggles to optimize std::string excessive usage. At the end of the day his question was about unexpected benchmarks he really has and the behavior can be fully explained (especially with disassembly). The takeaway: his way to use them leads to performance issues.

Your LazyCpp17 passes through integers in data, which is quite cheap. At the same time LazyCpp20 passes through std::string objects.
In the first case std::string object is needed for a very short scope and since this std::string is never actually used in process it could be easily optimized out.
In the second case these std::string objects are needed for your std::ranges::for_each loop since it passes them through, using them as a container/range/view for loop. So, these objects have to persist longer and are harder to optimize out.
If you avoid expensive std::string conversions/allocations, the results will differ. So, answering your original question, this has nothing to do with std::ranges::view, it is all about usage which brings "unnecessary" conversions on the second case.

So this is the cost we have to pay because of std::ranges overhead or some issue in the way this code has been writeen ?

@ShaktiMalik, this is totally about your usage of the library and having conversion to the std::string type which is expensive due to memory allocation. You should avoid it and results will differ. So, nothing here is about std::ranges::views. It is all about the usage. The specific way to workaround std::string usage depends on your needs. Updated the answer.

@DamirTenishev, but the OP is summing the lengths of the string representations of the integers (yeah, only the odd ones). At your link you've thrown the conversion to string away for all examples...

@Enlico, my version sums up the integers, so the results are not wasted, preventing the compiler from optimizing the underlying operations out. My point here is that if we avoid std::string, the pipeline functions themselves don't lead to any performance issues. The performance difference comes from ability of compiler to optimize out temporary `std::string' instances in the first and second cases.

@DamirTenishev, Transforming into a string can be a valid usecase for some usecase. In that case Lambda approach helps compiler achieve better optimization as compared to std::ranges. Is there something better we can do to achieve same performance with std::ranges without changing the problem statement ?

@ShaktiMalik, of course this is a valid use case, but the solution would depend on your real needs on the code coupling/decoupling. You may just couple process and transform and get this dirty solution or you can use std::accumulate instead of for_each. This totally depends on your real requirements. Your OP is "Unexpected runtime benchmarks with C++20 ranges" and I explained it. Now you changing the question to "How to handle some specific case". Don't you think it should be another question?

Not sure I understand the reasoning here. To my eyes, the Cpp20 variant does the same as Cpp17; only the integers that survive the filter get converted to strings. Then those strings get passed to the process function. Can you explain where the Cpp20 version, in your opinion, causes more strings to be created/copied? That should only happen when applying the transform before the filter, no?

@Wutz, this is not about filtering, this is about enumeration in the for_each loops from the compiler/optimizer perspective. While Cpp17 version enumerates through the std:vector<int> which has nothing to do with std::string, the Cpp20 version from compiler/optimizer perspective enumerates through the resulting set of std::sting objects which must persist until optimizations made, at least. Enlico's answer below shows that different compilers/optimizers could have different success ratio dealing with this.

Sorry, but I I'm still unsure. Views are evaluated lazyly. So for each iteration on the data view, the underlying vector iterator is advanced until the filter view finds the next element that matches. This element is then transformed into a string. This string is passed to the process function, then discarded before moving to the next. This still sounds the same as the cpp17 version to me, because under the hood of the view, it's still the vector of ints that's being iterated. I just don't understand why you say the cpp20 strings have to persist longer?

@Wutz, you are thinking from compiler standpoint. Try to think as an optimizer. Just look in assembly, it shows the result. There is a difference how language treats something and what could be assumed and used by optimizer.
